# Is it possible to hide a password parameter in the Logic Apps Designer?

Tags: c#, azure-logic-apps

I want my API App to show a password parameter in the Logic Apps Designer as (*) instead of the raw string. I added a custom MapType to SwaggerConfig.cs.

```
c.MapType<MyModel.Password>(() => new Schema {type = "string", format = "password" });
```

Parameters:

```
public class Parameters 
{
    // ...
    [Metadata("Password", null)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]             
    public Password Password { get; set; }
}

public class Password 
{
    public string password {get; set;}
}
```

It still shows the raw string in the designer. Am I missing something?

Comment: Great question - I don't believe this is supported today in the designer but I've reached out to a few people on our team to get an official answer.  I'll let you know once I hear back.

Comment: @jeffhollan Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer - it's currently not supported.  The only way to handle secure strings would be to deploy a Logic App via a deployment template like this one: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-logic-app-create/azuredeploy.json

And parameterize it with property type "SecureString".  That will remove the parameter value from view.  Then in the Logic App you would reference the parameter with @parameters('mypassword') or something.

So nothing you could do in the swagger to have it mask the value in the designer.  We are working on updates to the designer that could potentially accomplish this, but even if in the designer it masked the value, when you switched to the Logic Apps definition code-view you would be able to see it still.

If there is a different approach you'd like to see feel free to add an item in our product Uservoice: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps